# PDF viewer and annotate with comments in web page using angular

Tags: angular, pdf, annotations

I am able to render my PDF in webpage using pdf.js in Angular. I also need to annotate the PDF, capture annotated text and provide comments and save the PDF in the webpage. Please let me know how can I do this. I am new to angular.

Comment: It would help if you provided a more specific question. What have you tried?

Comment: Adobe's new View SDK will allow you to embed the PDF, let users comment on it, and then save it to a repository somewhere. After the save, you can use another PDF library tool to find the comments and get the text under them.

https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/viewsdk.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @joelgeraci

Comment: @VRK were you successful in integrating annotations and bookmarking in pdf angular?

Answer (score 1):

The most recent release of the Adobe DC View SDK is a PDF viewer that functions similarly to PDF.js in that it is entirely client-side but **now** does offer annotation capabilities with callbacks that will let you capture comments in your own repo without having to parse the PDF.

https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/viewsdk.html

Answer (score 0):

PDF.js does not support adding/editing annotations, nor interactive form filling.

You would either have to manually add annotating yourself, or find another solution.

If you are looking for suggestions on possible existing solutions you should check out https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Instead of posting the answer or link to the verified solution, do not redirect to another search.